# Predicting missing letters in a word

Tags: machine-learning, python, natural-language, reinforcement-learning, tensorflow

I am stuck with this machine learning problem.

For input, we have a word in which some letters are missing, e.g., word = 'in---m-nt'. Then we can make up to 6 guesses.

guess1 = 'e', then word = 'in--ement'

guess2 = 'a', then word = 'in--ement'

guess3 = 'x', then word = 'in--ement'

guess4 = 'c', then word = 'inc-ement'

guess5 = 'r', then word = 'increment'

succeed!

Or

guess5 = 'k', then word = 'inc-ement'

guess6 = 'x, then word = 'inc-ement'

Fail!

I want to train a model to achieve the highest success probability.

This seems like a reinforcement learning problem, which unfortunately I am not very familiar with.

I am relatively familiar with CNN in NLP, but I couldn't think of what the training data structure looks like.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Wouldn't a simple estimate of the frequencies of every word suffice?  With those, and given a partial word, you would examine the probability tree of all possible sequences of guesses, attribute it with a reward of +1 for all words at depths of 6 or less and a reward of 0 otherwise, and backtracking from leaves to the root you would directly compute the expected reward (chance of success) at each node.  Then, you need only follow the edges along the path of maximal expected reward.

Answer (score 2):

This problem looks very much like the masked language modeling task that is used for pre-training of BERT and similar models.

The training procedure is:

- You replace a randomly selected fraction of tokens with a special `[MASK]` token, or `-` in your example;
- You embed the tokens (in this case characters) and process them with a stack of layers. BERT uses the Transformer, but here 1D CNN should do the job;
- Do a character prediction with a linear projection and softmax. Technically, you need to do it for each character, but you only consider the loss at the places where you replaced the original character with the `-`.

In this way, you can generate as many training instances as necessary.